Excel sequence function does not work within a table
I have the following formula as in table.
in cell D2 i have: =SEQUENCE(WEEKNUM(DATE(B1,12,31))-1,, WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(B1,1,1)-1,1,"1110111"),7)
in cell E2 i have: =MONTH(D2)
It looks like this:

When i now try to insert a table using the range, i end up with Spill errors:

Anyone have as solution for this?
fyi - the formula lists the date of every weekly thursday in the year.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531#:~:text=Spilled%20array%20formulas%20are%20not%20supported%20in%20Excel%20tables%20themselves%2C%20so%20you%20should%20place%20them%20in%20the%20grid%20outside%20of%20the%20Table.  "Spilled array formulas are not supported in Excel tables themselves"

The formula which I have commented here was for range not for structured references

A possible workaround is to create an empty table with the right number of rows and columns, then use a formula based on the row. Note that this is normally header plus 52 rows, but 53 in case of a year that starts with a Thursday e.g. 2026 or indeed a leap year that starts on a Wednesday e.g. 2048.
=WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(B$1,1,1)-1,1,"1110111")+(ROW()-ROW(Table1[#Headers])-1)*7

and
=MONTH([@[Dates For Year]])


